# Discovering Server's IP on Client-Server App (iOS/Android & Windows)

Tags: c#, android, ios, networking, udp

I'm building an Server-Client app

- Working in local network
- Client is an iOS/Android app
- Server a Windows App (C#).

My problem is that the **Server's local IP is not fixed** so I can't connect my client to it. *(In my use case, I can't have a fix IP for the Server or a manual IP setting on the client.)*

I was thinking of two way for the iOS/Android **Client to discover the IP**:

- On the Client check every 192.168.1.XXX IP with the port I'm using (seems very slow compare to the amount of time the user hope to spend with the app)
- On the server do a UDP broadcast (but then I would need to do it each second for the Client to be able to discover it anytime?)

Those two ways seems overkill and slow for an app that used at most once a day and for a very quick use. What would be your solution in that case?

Comment: Look into [Bonjour](https://www.apple.com/ca/support/bonjour/) and other similar zeroconf services.